# What are the open-source tools available for Czech text normalization (for spoken transcription)?

Tags: tools, czech

I am looking to perform following normalization for speech-to-text and text-to-speech. Let's look at the examples:

1. `V její dlouhé historii bychom našli celou řadu důležitých dat a jedním z nich je určitě i 8. prosinec roku 1890.`

   - hyp1:`V její dlouhé historii bychom našli celou řadu důležitých dat a jedním z nich je určitě i osmý prosinec roku osmnáct set devadesát`
   - hyp2: `V její dlouhé historii bychom našli celou řadu důležitých dat a jedním z nich je určitě i osmý prosinec roku tisíc osm set devadesát`
2. `A právě tady se našlo snad nejvíc stop po magdalenienských lovcích, kteří zde před 11-17000 lety tábořili.`

   - hyp1: `A právě tady se našlo snad nejvíc stop po magdalenienských lovcích, kteří zde před jedenácti až sedmnácti tisíci lety tábořili.`
3. `Dnes tu na 23 ha můžete vidět na 7000 druhů dřevin a bylin z 5 kontinentů.`

   - hyp1: `Dnes tu na dvaceti třech hektarech můžete vidět na sedm tisíc druhů dřevin a bylin z pěti kontinentů.`

The tools and resources I have found:

- (Czech + many other lang) https://pypi.org/project/many-stop-words/
- (Relevant paper) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228861975_Normalization_of_Czech_vowels_from_continuous_read_texts
- (Not so relevant paper - uses stemming, lemmatization) http://textmining.zcu.cz/publications/inscit20060710.pdf
- https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words
- https://github.com/kucharovic/czech-money-to-words
- https://github.com/kslazarev/numbers_and_words

Answer (score -1):

ChatGPT 3.5 can handle it today. I think that the output is free because there is no copyright input. The request can be entered in Czech, English, and probably in many other major languages.

Comment: Did you evaluate the ChatGPT 3.5 output with some Gold standard/manual corrections and can you give numbers on how well it can do this?

Comment: @SirCornflakes The question was not about the output quality. So the answer is no. Providing numbers is a good topic for academic research.

Comment: And, BTW, ChatGPT is *not open source* despite the misleading name of its producer (Open AI).

Comment: And, while the user input (the prompt) may be copyrighted or not, the undisclosed training data for Chat GPT contain copyrighted material.

Comment: I’d generally consider ChatGPT a **baseline**, to include in the **question**, and then the question can be formulated in terms of the baseline.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SirCornflakes The clue here is, that if you/bot does not do major changes, the output cannot be relicensed. To: Community My answer is based on personal research.